# Chart Js - Group(average) y axis values against same x axis in line/scatter chart

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, linechart, scatter

I have datasets with x, y values x denotes date y denotes values.and i have successfully generated a chart. look at the pic attached below

[image: **Generated result**]

I'm using this code to generate the chart (generated using the above chart)

```
 var config = {
      type: 'scatter',
      data: {
        //labels: this.HoursStrings,
        datasets: [{
          data: yserires, // example data [{x:2019/01/02,y:12},{x:2019/01/02,y:12}}]                                
          fill: true,
          borderColor: "#3e82f7",
          yAxesGroup: "1"
        }]
      },
      options: {
         responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: false,
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        showLines: true, 
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: true,
          callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
              var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
              var day = moment(new Date(value.x)).format(self.timeformat);
              var point = value.y + " " + self.unityType
              return point;
            }
          } //
        },
        hover: {
          mode: 'nearest',
          intersect: true
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              unit: self.timeUnit
            },
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              userCallback: function (value, index, values) {
                return self.roundValues(value) + " " + self.unityType
              }
            }
          }]
        },
        elements: {
          line: {
              tension: .1, // bezier curves
          }
       }
      }
    };

    setTimeout(() => {
      var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");
      this.chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
      this.chart.update()
    }, 50)
```

**Expected Result**

how can group different y-axis values against the same x-axis values (***should be one single value like the average of y-axis***) is there any ***build in functions available in chart js*** or I need to group those value before binding the chart.

**Note: The date should be grouped (averaged) by day/hour/week/month**
like below image 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your array getting the mean value from the data before feeding it to the graph:

```js
// Your data array
let array = [{ x: '2019/01/02', y: 12 }, { x: '2019/01/02', y: 13 }]
// The output data for Chart js
var output = [];
// Get the non-unique values and add them to an array
array.forEach(function (item) {
    var existing = output.filter(function (v, i) {
        return v.x == item.x;
    });

    if (existing.length) {
        var existingIndex = output.indexOf(existing[0]);
        if (!Array.isArray(output[existingIndex].y))
            output[existingIndex].y = [output[existingIndex].y]
        output[existingIndex].y = output[existingIndex].y.concat(item.y);
    } else {
        if (typeof item.value == 'string')
            item.value = [item.value];
        output.push(item);
    }
});

// Compute the mean
console.dir(output.map(val => {
    val.y = (val.y).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / (val.y).length
    return val
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with chart js, but from my experience with D3 and time series visualization in general, the result you are seeing is the expected behavior. I.e. the time series visualization is constructed as a continuous line intersecting all data points, in the order the data points are specified.

So to answer your question about grouping, I would say yes, you need to group the data yourself before creating a chart.

First, however, you need to consider what grouping means - is it an average, a sum, a minimum, a maximum, or something different. I'm guessing you'll want an average, but it will depend on your use case and analysis needs.

I've written a short bit of code, that groups an array of entries by calculating the average of reoccurring x values:

```js
const data = [
  { x: '2019/01/28', y: 19 },
  { x: '2019/01/29', y: 15 },
  { x: '2019/02/02', y: 12 },
  { x: '2019/02/02', y: 13 },
  { x: '2019/02/02', y: 14 },
  { x: '2019/02/02', y: 15 },
  { x: '2019/02/02', y: 18 },
  { x: '2019/02/02', y: 21 },
]

const dataGrouper = {}

data.forEach((dataPoint) => {
  if (!dataGrouper[dataPoint.x]) {
    dataGrouper[dataPoint.x] = []
  }
  dataGrouper[dataPoint.x].push(dataPoint)
})

const groupedData = []

Object.keys(dataGrouper).forEach((groupingKey) => {
  const sum = dataGrouper[groupingKey].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return accumulator + currentValue.y
  }, 0)
  groupedData.push({
    x: groupingKey,
    y: sum / dataGrouper[groupingKey].length
  })
})

console.log({groupedData})
```

Comment: Why the downvote? 
If something is wrong or not clear, please elaborate, so I can remedy it.

Comment: fixed it for ya